# How to Identify the file output format on a VB excel script

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VB script for excel that's working almost perfectly for my desired purpose, it splits huge files into many smaller, 50.000 lines files.
But it's saving in XLS, and I need them on CSV, I just can't find out how.
Is there any simple parameter I could change here to achieve this?

```
Sub Test()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ThisSheet As Worksheet
    Dim NumOfColumns As Integer 
    Dim RangeToCopy As Range
    Dim RangeOfHeader As Range        'data (range) of header row 
    Dim WorkbookCounter As Integer 
    Dim RowsInFile                    'how many rows (incl. header) in new files? 

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 

    'Initialize data 
    Set ThisSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    NumOfColumns = ThisSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    WorkbookCounter = 1 
    RowsInFile = 50000                   'as your example, just 1000 rows per file 

    'Copy the data of the first row (header) 
    Set RangeOfHeader = ThisSheet.Range(ThisSheet.Cells(1, 1), ThisSheet.Cells(1, NumOfColumns))

    For p = 2 To ThisSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count Step RowsInFile - 1 
        Set wb = Workbooks.Add

        'Paste the header row in new file 
        RangeOfHeader.Copy wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1")

        'Paste the chunk of rows for this file 
        Set RangeToCopy = ThisSheet.Range(ThisSheet.Cells(p, 1), ThisSheet.Cells(p + RowsInFile - 2, NumOfColumns))
        RangeToCopy.Copy wb.Sheets(1).Range("A2")

        'Save the new workbook, and close it 
        wb.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\TF_COMBAT_EASTER_GAMES_2_" & WorkbookCounter
        wb.Close

        'Increment file counter 
        WorkbookCounter = WorkbookCounter + 1 
    Next p

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
    Set wb = Nothing 
End Sub
```

Comment: u are using excel interop right ?

Comment: VB.NET, VBA, and VBScript are **not the same**. Please call things properly, and use the appropriate tags. *Your code seems to be in VBA*.

Comment: Every time you use the wrong tags, you make a [kitten sad](https://i.imgur.com/7Dup7Ve.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this :

```
    wb.SaveAs("C:\Temp\output.csv", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSVWindows)
    wb.Close(false)
    'wb is the WORKBOOK
```

Comment: perfect :)
Thank you very much!!

Comment: if it solved the problem, please mark it as the answer